# Python GUI framework for small projects

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, file-browser

I'm looking for a GUI framework in Python that allows for the following things:
- Change variables of my code within the GUI before executing the main code
- Display a file browser to set the path of files that are needed for my script
- checkboxes for on/off

I have no experience with GUI frameworks, as I'm only programming for a scientific purpose (particle physics data analysis).
After a little bit of Google search, I've found that QT should be a good framework. However, I wonder if this isn't over the top for my very basic needs. 
Can anyone recommend a user friendly GUI framework that can handle what I want to do?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Nothing comes close to PyQt4 (my personal opinion). I have been using it for 3 years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://www.wxpython.org/ It is cross platform, and in my view easier for small project needs than QT.

Or for scientific purposes see ipython notebook. It allows interactive widgets with simple controls (e.g. checkboxes, sliders), but not more complex things like file browser. You can see examples here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tree/master/examples/Interactive%20Widgets